# PhpStorm XDebug and OSX Maverick

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

After a good effort at trying to configure XDebug in PHPStorm on my mac, I still get the "waiting for incoming connection key..." I've seen this issue on the internet, but none of the solutions yielded success.

php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/xedbug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: I'd suggest checking these links first: 1) http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ 2) http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm 3) http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Configuring+PHP+Environment 4) http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/436626?tstart=0

Comment: But what's more important -- how do you debug? Do you have a confirmation that xdebug is actually installed `<?php phpinfo();` ? You can collect detailed logs from **PhpStorm side** -- http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202 as well as **xdebug side** -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log  (Do not forget to restart after making changes to php.ini)

Comment: No, in phpinfo() xdebug is not installed

Comment: In such case, from  phpinfo() output, in the header table -- look for **Loaded Configuration File** field -- I guess this file is different from what you have edited before. If it's the same -- please restart Apache (or even whole computer).

Comment: There's a typo in the line with `zend_extension`: it says "xedbug" instead of "xdebug".

Answer (score 1):

Reference page for Xdebug setup: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-xdebug.html

Check your php.ini config, the snippet you provide is not in line with the suggestions.

I had a similar issue - in my case I found a php.ini parse error by checking the apache error logs (in the console app). The error log may also help.

Answer (score 0):

You might also make sure you have an "extensions_dir" directive in the php.ini pointing to the xdebug directory:

extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525"

This fixed my installation or in your case:

extension_dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib"